# which program is really running?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.04, path

I am running a self-compiled version on python2.7, --prefix=$HOME, so as not to interfere with the standard installation of python2.6 (on Ubuntu 10.04). Had some problem importing the ssl modules, tracked down the problem, re-compiled my python2.7 and came to test it:

```
$ ~/bin/python2.7 -c "import ssl"
```

Looking good, double check

```
$ python2.7 -c "import ssl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jab/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Eh? There's no other installation of python2.7 on this machine

```
$ which python2.7
~/bin/python2.7
$ echo $PATH
/home/jab/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:...
$ for dir in $(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' '); do ls $dir/python2.7 2>/dev/null; done
/home/jab/bin/python2.7
```

Just to be extra sure:

```
$ python2.7 -c "import sys; print sys.executable"
/home/jab/bin/python2.7

$ $(which python2.7) -c "import sys; print sys.executable"
/home/jab/bin/python2.7
```

Enough with the context already. The question is: why does this work?

```
$(which python2.7) -c "import ssl"
```

when this does not?

```
$ python2.7 -c "import ssl"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jab/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Comment: To see where the imports are coming from, add `-v`. Is there a difference between `python2.7 -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'` and `$(which python2.7) -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'`? What if you add `-s`? What if you add `-S`?

Comment: $ python2.7 -v gives the same error, $ ~/bin/python2.7 -v shows that ssl is a builtin module. -s and -S make no difference to the outputs